# C++ using capturing lambda inside virtual method

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, virtual-functions, dynamic-dispatch

I tried to use the following C++ code, but it fails to compile with a `no matching function for call to ...` error for the call to `z` inside `bar::s` when compiling with g++ 4.9.2 and `--std=c++11`:

```
template <class T>
class foo {
    public:
        virtual void s( T scale , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
        }
};

template <class T>
class bar : public foo<T> {
    public:
        T z( T init , T (*f)( T a , T& x , const T& y ) , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
        }
        void s( T scale , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
            this->z( ((T)0) , [=]( T a, T& l, const T& r ) {return ((l+=scale*r)?((T)0):((T)0));} , rhs );
        }
};

int main () {
    bar<float>* a = new bar<float>();
    foo<float>* b = new foo<float>();
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles if I remove the `virtual` in front of the method definition and also if I remove the captured `scale` from the the lambda. If understand the issue correctly, it works like this: When the method is not virtual, the lambda with capture is used via the `operator ()` of its associated type. When the method is virtual, that operator can't be used because it can't be called via dynamic dispatch, only via a normal method call. But the lambda can't be converted to a function pointer either, because that conversion is only available for captureless lambdas. And I assume that `z` is called via dynamic dispatch if `s` is virtual, even though `z` is not virtual. Is that analysis correct?

What I don't get is why `z` can't be called via a normal method call - it is not virtual, after all. What I also don't get is why removing the template parameters and replacing all `T`s with `float`s makes the compilation fail for both the virtual and the non-virtual case (removing the captured `scale` still allows successful compilation).

**In any case, is there a simple and somewhat efficient way of fixing this?** I would like to use lambdas with captures (or something similar) in both virtual and non-virtual methods of template classes. I know of `std::function`, but it's quite heavyweight. And captureless lambdas are quite a bit less powerful than lambdas with captures, so they probably won't be able to solve my problems.

PS: If you want to know what `z` is supposed to be doing: It is a combination of what would be `zipWith` followed by `foldl` in Haskell (or somewhat like mapreduce with two input lists if you don't know Haskell) and can be used for most unary and binary operations using `foo`s. In my original implementation, `init` was not of type `T`, and instead used as type an additional template parameter that was removed here for simplicity's sake.

Comment: You need a `std::function`.  Capturing lambdas can't decay to function pointers

Comment: With gcc 8, the code compiles for me only by removing the capture (and also returning something from `z`). The virtual-ity is irrelevant. Only non-capturing lambdas can be converted to plain function pointers.

Comment: The `virtual` is a red herring. The code won't compile without the virtual either. You just don't get the error until you try to call the `bar::s` method. Add this line to your code: `a->s(0, foo<float>());`.The same error appears. To fix this, make `z` accept a functor: `template<typename F> T z( T init, F&& f, const foo<T>& rhs ) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a template.

`virtual` here doesn't actually have anything to do with your problem.  The problem is that raw function pointers can't carry any state with them, and so lambdas with captures can't be converted to function pointers.

Instead of a raw function pointer, you should make `z` a template that accepts any type as its second argument:

```
template <class T>
class foo {
    public:
        virtual void s( T scale , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
        }
};

template <class T>
class bar : public foo<T> {
    public:
        template <typename F>
        T z( T init , F&& f, const foo<T>& rhs ) {
            f(/*some args*/);
        }
        void s( T scale , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
            this->z( ((T)0) , [=]( T a, T& l, const T& r ) {return ((l+=scale*r)?((T)0):((T)0));} , rhs );
        }
};

int main () {
    bar<float>* a = new bar<float>();
    foo<float>* b = new foo<float>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8579b330781ecba5)

Now that `z` accepts your lambda by its actual type, its state can be carried along, and everything works.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to be working. I hope it doesn't kill the performance.

Comment: It may actually perform better than a function pointer, since the call to `F::operator()` can be resolved at compile time.  With a function pointer or `std::function` that call may have to be resolved at runtime, which can represent some level of overhead.

Comment: virtual has lots to do with the OP's problem; when it isn't virtual, the never-called `s` is skipped by the compiler, so the compiler doesn't complain about the bad code in it.  :)  With virtual, it is implementation defined if the never-called `s` is instantiated (but all compilers I know of do it).  So if the OP's problem is "it won't compile", virtual matters; if the OP's problem is "it won't work", well, then, less so.

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond Chen pointed out, the virtuality is indeed a red herring.

For the time being, I decided to go with this ugly workaround, but I won't accept my answer, because it is not a real solution:

```
template <class T>
class foo {
    public:
        virtual void s( T scale , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
        }
};

template <class T>
class bar : public foo<T> {
    public:
        T z( T init , T (*f)( T a , T& x , const T& y ) , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
        }
        template <class U>
        U z2( U init , T capture_0 , T capture_1 , U (*f)( T capture_0 , T capture_1 , U a , T& x , const T& y ) , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
            return init;
        }
        void s( T scale , const foo<T>& rhs ) {
            this->z2<T>( ((T)0) , scale , ((T)0) , []( T c0 , T c1 , T a, T& l, const T& r ) {return ((l+=c0*r)?((T)0):((T)0));} , rhs );
            //this->z( ((T)0) , [=]( T a, T& l, const T& r ) {return ((l+=scale*r)?((T)0):((T)0));} , rhs );
        }
};

int main () {
    bar<float>* a = new bar<float>();
    foo<float>* b = new foo<float>();
    a->s(0,*b);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and allows me to use `z2` with up to 2 "pseudo-captures" of the right type, with or without virtuality and even with the additional template parameter that I left out in the question. Unneeded captures can simply be set to 0 and ignored.